# Android WebView orientation change

Tags: android, webview, orientation

I have a pager where I am using `WebView`s to display images. I have used `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to prevent reload of data during orientation changes. But whenever I change orientation, the image set shifts to one side for an instant before being reset to the appropriate position. Does this happen to everyone? Is there any other property I have to set to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

When an orientation is changed the views/fragments need to be reloaded in order to display on the entire screen.  What you are seeing is the expected result when prevent reload of data during orientation change